# datastore viewer HTTP response was too large: 37877503. The limit is: 33554432

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When trying to use the "Datastore Viewer" in the appengine administration console online ...i.e. https://appengine.google.com/datastore; instead of seeing the viewer as usual, I get:

HTTP response was too large: 37877503. The limit is: 33554432.

How can I get the view back working?

Is there something about my data that caused this?  If so, what can I do?

Comment: It may be, that your request is returning way too much data. Try to narrow the search criteria or exclude large columns (blobs, clobs, etc).

Comment: @Jk yeah that the thing, it returns that just trying to view the page so I am not entering any search criteria yet.  Maybe the default query is returning too much.